# MassTransit publishing custom properties for Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

Does anyone know how I can publish `ApplicationProperties` (aka custom properties) to Azure Service Bus via the MassTransit Publish?

In the native ASB client library, we can do this...

```cs
var message = new ServiceBusMessage(msg);
message.ApplicationProperties.Add("foo", "bar");
```

But I can't see how to do that in MassTransit. Looking at the overloads for the `Publish` method, the closest thing I can see is the headers - ie...

```cs
await _bus.Publish(new SomeEvent { SomeProperty = "some-value" },
    context =>
    {
        context.Headers.Set("MyCustomProperty", "my-custom-value");
    },
cancellationToken);
```

**UPDATE: I wrote the above snippet, as an example of what I'm doing - but it wasn't an exact copy. It turns out after seeing Chris's answer - that the above snippet *does* work - but in my actual code, "some-value" was actually a boolean - which is what the issue was!**

But that just adds headers to the MT message envelope - not ASB custom properties.

Ie. in my first example, this is where I see the field in Azure Service Bus explorer...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header is a string, or can be rendered as a string using a the built in `IFormatter` type, it should be copied to the `ApplicationProperties` collection.

For instance, using:

```cs
await endpoint.Send(new PingMessage(), context =>
{
    context.Headers.Set("Easy-Header", "Easy-Value");
});
```

Produces the header as shown:

[image]

Comment: Thank for the quick reply a Chris. Can you think of why my second code snippet doesn't work? I'm not seeing the custom properly appearing when inspecting it ASB Explorer. It works in my first snippet when not using MT. In the masstransit snippet, I do see the header in the message JSON itself though.

Comment: It looks like I'm doing the same as your example.

Comment: No clue, maybe look at it using the Azure Portal, I'm not sure when the Windows-based Service Bus Explorer was last updated. The SDK has changed a lot since it was written.

Comment: ACK!!! Sorry - I'm back at my desk now, and just compared my second snippet in my StackOverview post with my _actual_ code - and in the real code I was trying to set it to a boolean value - not a string. I've just tried with a string value, and it's worked :) Thanks again for your help with this :)